# How to get the count of each unique item in a many to many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an `ingredients` table containing unique ingredients:

```
ID    INGREDIENT
1    Sugar
2    Egg
3    Vanilla
```

I have a `recipe` table containing various recipes:

```
ID    RECIPE
1    Eggs Florentine
2    Hash Browns
3    Hamburger
```

There is a `many to many` relationship between both tables. Therefore there's an intermediate table like this:

```
ID    INGREDIENT_ID    RECIPE_ID
1    1    1
2    7    1    
3    1    6
etc.
```

I need to write a query which will tell me the number of times each ingredient is used in the recipes. Something look like this:

```
Sugar(27), Egg(242), Vanilla(5), ...
```

My feeling is I need to use the intermediate table, but I cannot get it to work.

Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: `select count(1), INGREDIENT_ID from many_to_many group by INGREDIENT_ID` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks. This is nice, but is it possible to list the ingredient name instead of the id?

Comment: @TomBrock: join the two tables

Comment: @TomBrock posted as answer with ingredient name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(1), INGREDIENT
from many_to_many 
join ingredients_table it on INGREDIENT_ID =it.ID
group by INGREDIENT
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can use the group by function to do that here is the link: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

in your case you could do like:

```
Select count(ingredient_id) from recipe_ingredient_table group by ingredient_id
```

if you want to add another value like ingredient name you can include the :

```
Select count(rit.ingredient_id),i.name 
from recipe_ingredient_table rit 
join ingredient i on (i.id = rit.ingredient_id) 
group by rit.ingredient_id,i.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT I.INGREDIENT, COUNT(I.ID)
FROM INGREDIENTS I
JOIN RECIPE R ON I.ID = R.ID
GROUP BY I.INGREDIENT
```